# How to add (any type )value to an array(by specified index) in php language

Tags: php, arrays

As title, I did it like below:

```
$array=array(0,1,2,3);
$result=array();
function makeArray($array,$result,$value){
$str='$result';
for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $str.='['.$i.']';
}
$str.='="'.$value.'";';
eval($str);
return $result;
}
```

It can realize result when param $result is an empty array,but It report an error when $result is an array.
Error like :
Cannot use a scalar value as an array.
Anyways can realize it? 
Thanks first!

Comment: the string you are creating look like `$result[0][1][2][3]=$value` is that the intent?... and put that eval down...you're going to hurt someone

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you want to pass an array to a function and have it modify the array, pass it by reference.

Comment: Yes , $result[0][1][2][3]=$value that's I want.I want add value to a dynamic deep index array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pass by reference, not `eval`:

```
function makeArray($indexes, &$result, $value) {
    $here =& $result;
    foreach ($indexes as $i) {
        if (!(isset($here[$i]) && is_array($here[$i]))) {
            $here[$i] = array();
        }
        $here =& $here[$i];
    }
    $here = $value;
}

$array=array(0,1,2,3);
$result=array();
makeArray($array, $result, 3);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        [3]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Putting `&` before a function parameter means it will be passed by reference, so modifications to the variable inside the function will affect the original variable that was passed. And using `=&` in an assignment assigns a reference, so the target variable is an alias for the source.

Comment: I have a menu which some has sub,but I need a check when recursion all the menu.I have no good idear with it.If you're interesting at this,leave me a email,I post the source file to you.And thanks again!

Comment: I really want is that add a dynamic deep index to a array.Not one-dimensional,but many dimensionals array.

Comment: I've rewritten the function to use the indexes as deep indexes.

Comment: This question trouble me one day, You processed it. Great man!! I will study deep hard with PHP. Thanks Barmar.