# get multidimensional array value from keys in another array

Tags: php

I've got an array containing values I wish to use as keys, such as:

```
$keys = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");
```

The count and contents of these values will be changing dynamically within a loop.  I want them to become the keys of a multidimensional array, but the count of the keys array will always be changing, so while this would work for that first array of keys:

```
$multidimensional[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]] = "some value";
```

Later in the loop the keys may be something like:

```
$keys = array("first", "second", "gamma", "delta", "theta", "kappa");
```

So using this in the loop:

```
$multidimensional[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]] = "some value";
```

Will not work, and needs to be dynamic too based on the count of the keys.

I've gone through each of the array functions in the PHP manual and can't seem to find something that fulfills this purpose.  Am I totally overlooking something basic here?  Maybe some curly brace magic?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `$multidimensional`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add (any type )value to an array(by specified index) in php language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873351/how-to-add-any-type-value-to-an-arrayby-specified-index-in-php-language)

Comment: Strange, I just answered an almost identical question last night. Is this really a common need?

Comment: it sounds like your code could be better designed, frankly (i.e. there's probably an easier model for achieving what you want besides using arrays in this manner)

Comment: @Barmar:  modifying your answer to the other question helped me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There you go...

```php
function setMultidimensionalValue($value, array $keys, array $multidimensional)
{
  $node = &$multidimensional;
  foreach ($keys as $key)
  {
    if (!isset($node[$key]))
      $node[$key] = null;
    $node = &$node[$key];
  }
  $node = $value;
  return $multidimensional;
}

// Example of usage
$multidimensional = array();
var_dump(setMultidimensionalValue('value', array('first', 'second', 'third'), $multidimensional));
```